# Regular Expression replacing dash with space

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a problem how do i replace a single dash(-) with a single space.

I tried the following

```
$test = TEST-test;
preg_replace('\-', '/s', $test);
echo $test;
```

but no result.

thx,

Comment: `preg_replace` returns the result string, so it should be:   
`$test = preg_replace('/\-/', ' ', $test);`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Behold the `strtr`:

```
$test = strtr($test, '-', ' ');
```

Btw, your original code has `TEST-test`, that needs to be wrapped in quotes:

```
$test = 'TEST-test';
```

Comment: It worked, sorry can't vote up your answer not enough reputation points.]

Answer (score 0):

Use php str_replace() for this thing

```
$test = 'TEST-test';
$test=str_replace('-', ' ', $test);
echo $test;
```

Answer (score 0):

use sed

```
echo $test | sed 's/-/ /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

One regular expression to replace a `-` by a blank :

```
preg_replace('/-/',' ',$string);
```

You miss the regular expression delimiters.